# Globally defined exponential in a particular homogeneous space

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quotient-spaces

I'm currently working in a particular conformal compactification/completion of the Minkowski space-time, but I'm stuck at showing that the exponential of every vector field in it is globally defined. I've worked in the general case, since it's essentially the same as the particular case with $p=3$ and $q=1$.

I have a $p+q$-dimensional manifold, $M$, on which the orthogonal group $O(p+1,q+1)$ acts transitively. So we know that for every $m\in M$,
$$
M\cong O(p+1,q+1)/O(p+1,q+1)_m,
$$ where $O(p+1,q+1)_m$ is the stabilizer of $m$. My question is:

1. How can I show/see that the exponential of every vector field in $M$ is globally defined?

**Edit:** I also know that $M\cong \mathbb{S}^p\times\mathbb{S}^q /\mathbb{Z}_2$, if it helps.

Comment: I guess the vector field must satisfy some extra conditions (how is the vector fields related to the homogenous structure?)

Comment: I want to see that the exponential of the conformal fields, which wasn't globally defined in the original space, is now globally defined in $M$. @John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you're looking at a homogeneous space is irrelevant -- what's relevant is that $M$ is compact (since you said it's homeomorphic to $\mathbb S^p\times \mathbb S^q/\mathbb Z_2$).  On a compact manifold, every vector field is complete, meaning its flow exists for all time.

Comment: Thanks Jack, overnight I decided to go with that approach. Thanks for your answer. On the other hand, why is the homogeneity so important? My two references mention this fact as if it has some particular use.

Comment: @hjhjhj57: For the purpose of showing that flows exist for all time, it's the fact that it's a compactification that matters. But there are plenty of other reasons why the homogeneity is useful. Minkowski space itself is already  a homogeneous Lorentzian manifold, and the compactification embeds it into a homogeneous conformal Lorentzian manifold. This serves as a model space for conformal Lorentzian geometry in general, just as Euclidean space serves as a model for Riemannian geometry and the sphere for conformal geometry.

Comment: Thanks, Jack. PS: I'm a big fan of your books :)